# Why am I getting a parse error when using values in a Helm named template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In my Helm chart's `templates/_helpers.tpl` file, this named template is at line 1:

```
{{- define "mychart.foo" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" (include "anotherchart.bar" $.) .roleSuffix }}
{{- end -}}
```

When I run `helm template` against my chart, it produces this error:

> Error: parse error at (mychart/templates/_helpers.tpl:2): unexpected <.> in operand
> helm.go:84: [debug] parse error at (mychart/templates/_helpers.tpl:2): unexpected <.> in operand

I don't see anything wrong with my syntax. `.roleSuffix` will be available when the named template is `include`d, via its second parameter, inside a `range` loop. I have tried putting parentheses in various places.

Why does Helm refuse this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I was fixated on `.roleSuffix`, but `$.` was the problem. Apparently, you have to pass it as `$` instead. It seems somewhat inconsistent with passing `.` but apparently that's just how it works.

The corrected code:

```
{{- define "mychart.foo" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" (include "anotherchart.bar" $) .roleSuffix }}
{{- end -}}
```